# Why should we avoid 1+N query problems?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

It might sound a bit dumb but I'm not a DB expert.

For example, if we have a `User` model and a `Comment` model, and each comment belongs to a user, there are two ways of fetching all comments along with their users:

```
# 1.
@comments = Comment.all(:include => :user)

# 2. 
@comments = Comment.all()
@users = []
@comments.each do |comment| # Or we do the same loop in embedded code in the view
  @users << User.find(comment.user)
end
```

My question is, since both methods will fetch all comments and their user data (which means we read and transfer the same amount of information from the hard drive and through the internet), why is the second one considered as a bad practice?

Comment: Because more queries usually equal worse performance, and it's pointless to perform 100 queries that can be reduced to 2.

Comment: @DamienRoche What kind of overhead does a query have to make more queries worse performance?

Comment: I'll demonstrate in an answer..

Comment: this is also explained in "13 Eager Loading Associations" of the ActiveRecord Query Interface, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allow me to demonstrate why:

```
Message.count
13228

Benchmark.measure { Message.all.each(&:user) }
16s

Benchmark.measure { Message.all(include: :user).each(&:user) }
2s
```

With 100 rows, which is a more realistic fetch:

```
Benchmark.measure { Message.limit(100).each(&:user) }
0.12s

Benchmark.measure { Message.includes(:user).limit(100).each(&:user) }
0.01s
```

As you can see, around 10x faster and less stress on the database.

Comment: How would

`Message.all.map!{|message| message | message.user}`

compare?

Comment: @Drew I'm afraid that isn't valid syntax. Could you re-check? Either way, calling `message.user` without including will still result in 13k queries instead of 2.

Comment: Haha yeah, I couldn't recall what the command to merge two arrays is, but yeah anyway, I don't know why I was thinking that would be quicker! haha

Comment: @Drew haha! I actually thought you were going to say `{ |message| message || message.user }` which would of course only fetch message.

Comment: How would `Message.all.map!{|message| message |= message.user}` compare?*

Comment: @Drew still not valid syntax ;) do you mean `||=`? That basically says  `set message as message.user if message undefined, then return message`. It would result in message being returned every time and skip the `message.user` call.

Comment: @Drew I think I understand what you're trying to do with "merge two arrays". One array of `messages` and another of `users`. That's what `Message.includes(:user)` is a shortcut for.

Answer (score 2):

Hitting the DB again and again to get the `User` record associated with the `Comment` record will effect the performance of your application.

This becomes even more slow if the number of comments is too high and you are looping through it to get all the associated users.

Whereas in case of `Comment.all(:include => :user` only two queries will be fired all the time. One to get Comments and one to get all the associated users.